# Illustrator Script- Java script- Applying action to selection

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a script that will go through the selection and apply action to each group in the selection.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. select a couple of individual groups
2. apply an action to each group seperatly

My problem is that instead of applying it to each group it does it to all of them. I tried using a for loop but it didn't worked, I tried to deselect the group that passed the action but it failed to.

Here is my script:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for (i=0; i < doc.groupItems.length; i++)
{
    doc.groupItems[i].selected = true;
    app.doScript("300", "Set 1"); //Action name - Folder Name
    app.activeDocument.selection = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sel = app.selection;
app.activeDocument.selection = null;

for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    if (sel[i].constructor.name != 'GroupItem') continue;
    sel[i].selected = true;
    app.doScript("300", "Set 1"); // Action name - Folder Name
    sel[i].selected = false;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work until I changed "sel[i].selected = false;" to app.activeDocument.selection = null;

Comment: Well. Probably it depends on what your action does.